# Remove blank space after wrapped items

Tags: css, flexbox

I need a flexbox-layout for unknown number of elements, which wraps to next line when there is no more space available. But I need the whole layout (red border) to be centered inside container (green border), but I don't want items (yellow boxes) to be centered if they wraps.

After the items wraps to second line (items 6-8), outer red box does not center any more, because it takes all space that is available, leaving big whitespace around item number 5 and right edge of red line.

Is there any way to force the red box to only consume space it needs, and then gets centered?

[image: sample picture]

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex-container wrap">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy way out would be to add specific **width** to `flex-container`, so that the box doesn't increase in size.

Another option would be to add **margin** to `flex-container` or **padding** to `container`.

Note: It would be better to add width/margin/padding using **%** or **vw** instead of **px** so that it remains independent to screen size.

For example,

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10%;  
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex-container wrap">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```